# Check value of datatable cell c#

Tags: c#, datatable

I've tried to use other answers to similar questions and it doesn't seem to be working just right, I must be missing something.

Here is the code I've come up with based on other answers:

** indicate the places where Visual Studio shows problems in the code --

```
protected void submit_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["HMTDBCS"].ConnectionString);
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from Staff where username =@username and password=@password", con);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", username.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", password.Text);
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    int i = dt.Rows.Count;
    string accesslevel = *dt.Rows[i][6] *;
    for (int* i* = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
                {
        if (*accesslevel == 1 *)
        {
            // Redirect to Access Level 1 landing page
        }
        else if (*accesslevel == 2 *)
        {
            // Redirest to Access Level 2 landing page
        }
        else if (*accesslevel == 3 *)
        {
            // Redirect to Access Level 3 landing page
        }
        else
        {
            lblErrorMessage.Visible = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: First, you can not declare a new `i` variable in your `for` loop as `i` already exists above (`int i = dt.Rows.Count;`). Then your `accesslevel` variable is a `string` and `i`is an int. You can not compare `string` to `i` as is.
Finally I don't understand what you try to achieve with your `for` loop

Comment: `string accesslevel = *dt.Rows[i][6]*` You should convert the value to _ToString()_. `accesslevel == 1` should be `accesslevel == "1"`

Answer (score 1):

After initializing the `DataTable` you need to call `da.fill(dt)` to add read data to the datatable.

You have also defined `i` twice. you need to name a new variable in your for loop.

Comment: I've removed the first definition for i leaving only the definition in my for loop. Also put in the missing fill command for the datatable. Added "" around my 1, 2, & 3 accesslevel and things are looking better. But it still doesn't like this line--
string accesslevel = dt.Rows[i][6].ToString();
It says 'i' doesn't exist in the current context, which makes sense because i is defined in the for loop instead of above. Should I define i above and remove the definition from the for loop?

Comment: that specific line `string accesslevel = dt.Rows[i][6].ToString()` should be inside the 
for loop

Answer (score 0):

> You are missing one line over here. Actually you are not filling datatable using 
>     SqlDataAdapter , use the below code and try please.

```
 SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        int i = dt.Rows.Count;
```